# Backslash escape in indexOf

Tags: javascript

Why does **n** give **0** in the following instance :

```
var str = '\\nvga032.bmwgroup.net\QXE7868\Daten\IE\3_bookmarks.zzz'

var n = str.indexOf("\\");

alert(n) //0
```

Surely the escape character for a backslash is

> ```
> '\\'
> ```

Am I missing something? I am looking for a **single** backslash at the last position. I tried **lastIndexOf** as well, and that also gives zero. Are the two '.'s messing things up?

Comment: Your initial string probably doesn't give what you expect. it gives something like: "\nvga032.bmwgroup.netQXE7868DatenIE_bookmarks.zzz" with some special chars within

Answer (score 1):

`indexOf` matches on the *string* not the JavaScript source code used to create it.

A `\` character starts an escape sequence.

`\\` is the escape sequence for "A backslash".

The string assigned to `str` starts with `\\` which puts a backslash in position 0 in the data.

The string passed to `indexOf` consists entirely of `\\` which matches the first backslash in the data.

---

If you wanted to describe an escape sequence in a string you would use `\\\\` (i.e. the escape sequence for a backslash followed by another escape sequence for a backslash resulting in data consisting of two backslashes).

Comment: no actually looking for two backslashes, just the last single backslash

Comment: That would be `lastIndexOf` IIRC, but you are already getting the last backslash in the string — there is only one backslash in it. The ``\`` character starts an escape sequence, remember?

Comment: yes i just realised the string is not correct. It isnt escaped properly

Answer (score 1):

`"\\"` will be parsed down to a single blackslash. And then indexOf will look for that single backslash, which happens to be at the start of the string (n=0).

If you want to search for TWO backslashes, you'll have to `indexOf("\\\\")` (**FOUR** backslashes, which will be parsed down to two literal backslashes).

Comment: I actually just want the last backslash. I tried lastIndexOf, but that also gave me 0

Comment: That's also because your original string's backslashes were see as escaping the `Q`, `D`, `I`, etc... You'll have to double them there too: `var str='\\\\nvga...\\Q...\\Detc...';`

Comment: Remember: backslashes are metacharacters. They have no existence in a JS string as anything OTHER than metacharacters. If you want a literal backslashs in a JS string, you have to escape it: `str = "\foo"` is an escaped `f` followed by two letter O's. `str = "\\foo"` is a literal backslash followed by the word 'foo'.

Answer (score 1):

Your "str" variable most probably doesn't contain what you expected. Write instead:

```
var str = '\\\\nvga032.bmwgroup.net\\QXE7868\\Daten\\IE\\3_bookmarks.zzz'
var n = str.lastIndexOf("\\");
```